# How To Easily Get Gold Coins?

Tags: terraria

I've been trying to save up my money to buy the illegal gun parts, but their cost is 75 gold coins. Can someone please tell me how to easily get them? Thanks.

Comment: was pretty sure there is a higher coin, platinum I believe.

Comment: I can't delete this question. D: